# Yarn "competing" against Sqoop regarding Java Version

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn, sqoop

smoothly under Java JDK 8. Resource Manager starts flawlessly, but if I try to use Sqoop 1.4.7 to connect to my Oracle DB, it complains that Oracle Driver was compiled by a more recent version of Java Runtime:

[image]

The problem is that under Java JDK 9, Resource Manager will not run and, thus, Sqoop call for a mapreduce job when trying to import a table, for example. Reading the log files, I can see a lot of classes complaining. Thus, how can I make things work, if class file version 54 demands at least Java JDK 10?

What versions of Java JDK, Hadoop and Sqoop will work together?

Answer (score 1):

I managed how to work this out, after a lot of tests and failures: the problem, actually, was upon the jdbc driver used. Although java jdk 8 was the version running on my system, I realized that at the sqoop/lib I got a ojdbc10.jar (compatible with java 10). When I swaped it for the ojdbc8.jar everything worked just fine.